# Can nanotechnology build a virus?

Tags: biophysics, nanoscience

I heard that nanotechnology can arrange atoms the way one wishes. The atomic force microscope can control the arrangement. As the composition of the viruses is known, can by nanoprinting a virus be reproduced?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See e.g. https://journals.asm.org/doi/epub/10.1128/mSystems.00770-21

mSystems, July/August 2021  Volume 6  Issue 4  e00770-21

"The Future of Virology is Synthetic"

"Synthetic virology is a subdiscipline of virology that applies molecular, computational, and synthetic biology principles from the fundamentals obtained from naturally occurring viruses to engineer viruses. The first virus assembled from synthetic oligonucleotides was poliovirus (1), followed by the phiX174 bacteriophage (i.e., phage) (2). Synthetic viruses are built upon a previously sequenced genome, and then oligonucleotides are ordered and assembled synthetically (e.g., Gibson) (2)."

"Process of building synthetic viruses. First, viral nucleic acids must be extracted and then sequenced using massively parallel nucleic acid sequencing. After sequencing, computational pipelines assemble the viral genomes de novo. Once the viral genomes are assembled computationally, synthetic DNA and oligonucleotides (oligos) can be ordered. Next, the synthetic DNA and oligos can be assembled into full-length viral genomes using Gibson or Golden Gate assembly. Finally, the assembled viral genome can be converted into viral particles using in vitro transcription and translation into synthetic virions."

Comment: Thank you very much. Do you know can they build the capsid only without DNA strand?

Comment: @Mercury : google search for synthetic capsid seems productive, e.g., https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/acs.bioconjchem.9b00327